# Модули в C++ — что это и когда использовать?

Tags: c++, модули, c++-faq, c++20

Что такое модули? Зачем они нужны и как они отличаются от заголовочных файлов? Когда стоит использовать одно, а когда второе?

Comment: [What exactly are C++ modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22693950)

Comment: Вам нужен перевод ответа по ссылке, или вы делаете самоответ?

Comment: Есть еще такой доклад: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQb6EOk1RM0

Comment: Да, я бы тоже **почитал** про модули на русском

Answer (score 10):

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=vs-2019

> Что такое модули?

Модуль — это набор файлов исходного кода, которые компилируются независимо от единиц трансляции, которые их импортируют.

> Зачем они нужны и как они отличаются от заголовочных файлов?

- Модули устраняют или значительно снижают многие проблемы, связанные с
  использованием файлов заголовков, а также могут сократить время
  компиляции.
- Макросы, директивы препроцессора и неэкспортированные имена,
  объявленные в модуле, не видны и поэтому не влияют на компиляцию
  записи преобразования, которая импортирует модуль.
- Модули можно импортировать в любом порядке, не заботясь о
  переопределениях макросов.
- Объявления в импортируемой записи не участвуют в разрешении
  перегрузки или поиске имен в импортированном модуле.
- После компиляции модуля результаты сохраняются в двоичном файле,
  который описывает все экспортированные типы, функции и шаблоны. Этот
  файл может обрабатываться гораздо быстрее, чем файл заголовка, и
  может использоваться компилятором каждый раз, когда модуль
  импортируется в проект.

> Когда стоит использовать одно, а когда второе?

Рекомендуется, чтобы новые проекты использовали модули, а не файлы заголовков, насколько это возможно. Для больших существующих проектов в рамках активной разработки мы рекомендуем поэкспериментировать с преобразованием устаревших заголовков в модули, чтобы определить, будет ли получено осмысленное сокращение времени компиляции.