# Как работают модули из c++20?

Tags: c++, c++20

Решил таки посмотреть, какие изменения были введены в 20-ом стандарде и одно из первых изменений поставило меня в тупик: модули. Я долго пытался понять зачем их внедрили и как они должны работать (и я не про синтаксис и примеры использования).

Как я понял, модули могут послужить этакой альтернативой разделению кода на заголовочный и source файлы, однако! это разделение ведь возникло не просто так. Создали были вынуждены так сделать для того, чтобы сделать компилятор однопроходным. Компилятор при препроцессинге файла заменяет все директивы include на содержимое этих инклюдов, что является простой операцией и требует всего-то указать где эти инклюды искать (если они не в одном из стандартных местоположений). Но как компилятор обрабатывает модули? Вот он встречает директиву импорта модуля - его действия? Это не имя файла, он не знает где его искать если файл с этим модулем еще не встречался. Он должен перебрать исходники в поисках места где этот модуль экспортируется? Отложить текущий файл и заняться обработкой других пока не будет встречен нужный модуль? Как модули сказываются на производительности компилятора?

Comment: Это дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172241/Модули-в-c-что-это-и-когда-использовать............................

Comment: @user414567 там нет ответов на заданные мной вопросы. Единственное из того, что меня интересовало и что присутствует в выше приведенном ответе, это то, что после обработки модуля компилятор сохраняет данные в двоичном файле. Но главное что меня интересует: как компилятор обрабатывает импорт модуля? Этого я в вышеприведенном ответе на нашел

Comment: что имеется ввиду под "как компилятор обрабатывает импорт"? Но если посмотреть на другие языки, на тот же Делфи (да, я знаю, многие его не любят, путаютс Object Pascal:) ) то там как раз идея модулей на самих юнитах сделана и позволяет очень быстро компилить все.

Comment: @KoVadim юнитах трансляции вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: не путайте юниты трансляции в плюсах и юнит в делфи.

Comment: я не знаю дельфи, так что мне не понятно что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: тогда попробуйте ответить на вопрос выше.

Comment: @KoVadim по-моему я все описал в вопросе - мне нечего добавить помимо того, что я уже там написал...

Comment: я кажется понял вопрос. А как компилятор может поступить, если встретил то, что он не знает? может поругаться, а может как сишный компилятор предположить сигнатуру, а потом уже сверить. Думаю, плюсовыми модулями история такая же как и с обычными файлами и другими языками - система сборки должна обеспечить правильный порядок сборки.

Comment: "Я долго пытался понять зачем их внедрили и как они должны работать" - это прокачанные pre-compiled headers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот в статье https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/11/07/modular-hello-world/ дается как раз ответ на такой вопрос. Суть в том, что вначале нужно сделать "прекомпиляцию" модулей и компилятор нагенерирует специальные файлы. А потом уже делается классическая компиляция в привычном виде.

> Вот он встречает директиву импорта модуля - его действия?

найти в заданных путях имя файла модуля (да, теперь кроме инклудов, либ будет ещё один путь)

> Это не имя файла, он не знает где его искать если файл с этим модулем еще не встречался.

это как раз имя файла (по крайней мере в случае clang) и Вы сами должны задать, где его искать. Даже если он лежит в этом же каталоге (ох ох).

> Он должен перебрать исходники в поисках места где этот модуль экспортируется?

для этого программист должен запустить вначале компилятор в режиме генерации специально файла модуля.

> Отложить текущий файл и заняться обработкой других пока не будет встречен нужный модуль?

нет, просто по классике сказать "не знаю, что это, не буду компилировать"

> Как модули сказываются на производительности компилятора?

должны сказываться позитивно. Ведь теперь не нужно парсить миллионы строк кода хедеров.

Вот есть дока http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1441r1.pdf - где видно, что у них получилось в  где то в пару раз сократить время компиляции

и еще чуточку на эту тему https://cor3ntin.github.io/posts/compiletime/

Comment: конечно клевая фича - ускорение компиляции это всегда хорошо, да и кода нужно будет меньше писать, НО... Есть очень большая проблема с этим: как с этим работать тулам работающим с семантикой? Например у меня есть тула для токенизации кода на c/c++, которую я использую для подсветки в vim - как ей работать с модулями я вообще не представляю! С инклюдом все просто: поменял там определение функции - и после сохранения этого файла в любом юните трансляции будет известно что это за функция. А с модулем что? Нужно не только сохранить, но и получить из него файл модуля. Короче дополнительный геморой

Comment: Это не имеет отношение к вопросу - просто поделился первопричиной вопроса

Comment: просто нужно улучшить токенизатор. и всех делов то.

Comment: в том то и дело что нет - токенизатор то причем? Помните: нет, просто по классике сказать "не знаю, что это, не буду компилировать"? Так что если изменяется модуль, то на это уже нужен другой инструмент, который при сохранении файла сгенерит файл модуля и положит по определенному пути. А сдесь уже проблемы синхронизации типа: если не успел пересобраться модуль, а токенайзер начал работу.

Comment: токенайзер может читать скомпилированный модуль для получения необходимой информации

Comment: ну да, так я о чем? Проблема в компиляции модуля - токенайзер не может скомпилировать модуль (мало того, что это не его задача, так у него для этого и информации недостаточно), а может работать только с уже скомпилированными. А это означает, что кто-то их должен компилить. Тобишь +1 тула